# Fetch XML data from Steam API gamestats

Tags: php, xml, loops

I Google'd not long ago and came across this solution to loop out information from a XML page.

```
$url    = 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/ChetFaliszek/stats/L4D/?xml=1';
$achxml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach ($achxml->playerstats->game as $ach)
{
  $name = (string) $ach->NAME;
  echo $name. "<br>";
}
```

I think these lines of code will do the trick but I only get following error when I try to fetch the information: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...`. The link to the XML page (random guys XML) is in the $url parameter.

Now to the question: How do I fix this problem so I can see if this code will work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide a correct argument to foreach. It basically works, but if the XML changes, `->playerstats->game` might not exist any longer. Do a `var_dump($achxml->playerstats->game);` before the foreach line and add the output to your question. This might give some insight.

Comment: Thanks! The loop didn't work as I thought. I can't for example fetch any values from the giving "tags". The foreach-code is now `$achxml->achievements`. What shall I type to get for example the image of the achievement?

Comment: Erik, the [`simplexml` manual section has some basic examples](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) which I think are interesting for you to know about.

Comment: Many thanks! One more problem before I have fix this issue :) How do I list every achievement that's in the XML page? It only prints one achievement now. Code: `foreach($achxml->children() AS $ach) {
 $name = $ach->achievement->name;
 echo $name;
}`

Comment: I added an answer. Shows all: Iteration over children, access a tag's content (name) and the attribute (closed), just like on the basic usage page. Scroll down for attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One more problem before I have fix this issue :) How do I list every achievement that's in the XML page?

try:

```
foreach ($achxml->achievements->achievement as $achievement)
{
     echo $achievement->name, '(closed: ', (string) $achievement['closed'], ')';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! :) But it only prints `(closed: )`

Comment: My fault, it had missing the `->achievement` in the `foreach`.

Comment: Two more questions. How do I count closed and not closed achievements and how do I fetch other information than only `iconClosed`, `iconOpen`, `name`, and `description`? In the statistic page for Left 4 Dead I linked to in my first post, you can see more information about the playerstats than for example Red Orchestra 2 (e.g. favorite campaign, most used weapon and so on).